# Without using the value for $\sin 18^°$ or $\cos 36^°$, prove that $4\sin 36^°\cos 18^°=\sqrt 5$

Tags: trigonometry

Without using the value for $\sin 18^°$ or $\cos 36^°$,
prove that $4\sin 36^°\cos 18^°=\sqrt 5$

I tried to square it use some trigonometric formulas but could solve it.

Comment: See this PDF: https://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf

Comment: this is the same thing as putting the values.!! we dont have to plug in values.!!

Comment: What? You can calculate $\sin 36^\circ$ as in that pdf, and then use the half angle formula in the inane form $\cos 18^\circ = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} ( 1 + \cos 36^\circ ) } = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} ( 1 + \sqrt{1 - (\sin 36^\circ)^2 })} $ if you want to avoid those two values...

Comment: so basically we are using the value of sin36

Comment: Sure, which you didn't preclude (you only precluded $\sin 18^\circ$ and $\cos 36^\circ$) - the question is inane beyond the point presented at that link.

Comment: ya basically we dont have to use values which are not common..!!

Comment: It's hard to imagine an easier way to solve this than how the pdf suggests, with a 36-72-72 triangle.

Comment: ohk.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!